# Javascript Partial Search

Tags: javascript, algorithm, search

Essentially I have an array that I need to perform a partial text search (all elements are English strings) on. The array can have about 1000 elements and I need to be able to search (efficiently) for a string within each element.

Is my only option a complete loop through the array running each string against .match()? Or is would there be a better alternative?

One idea I had was to split the 1000 element array into chunks of about 100, then .join.match() that section. That way if an element was found we could look through it, if not we could move to the next chunk. Obviously the chunk size would need to be tweaked a bit, but would that provide a viable solution?

Comment: use array.join and while(match = RE.exec(...)) {} with a global regex. You can use RE.lastIndex to find the item you match at each iteration of your while loop

Comment: Do you really need regular expressions? What kind of text is it? Source code? English text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using an [inverted index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index). [Here's a nice implementation in Javascript](http://dev.theladders.com/archives/2006/11/introducing_javascript_fulltex_1.html), very much in Lucene style. Although I wonder if it's worth it for only 1000 elements, but I guess it also depends on how long is each element.

Comment: Each element is fairly short, probably about 50 characters each. As well, if I break up the elements into individual sections instead of keeping them as one massive list I might be able to speed up the search even more before implementing a search algorithm, but this looks very interesting, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Does this one do it for you?

```
<script>
var str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent ut erat vitae nulla dignissim sodales. Duis mattis, massa ac adipiscing lacinia, massa velit suscipit turpis, ut eleifend risus nisl sed dui. Suspendisse vitae malesuada purus. Vestibulum at pharetra justo. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Morbi sit amet risus augue. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed luctus, tellus vehicula sollicitudin tempus, quam dolor scelerisque dolor, ac blandit libero nisi quis metus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Integer id elit nunc. Quisque tincidunt tempor ipsum, quis porta metus mollis at. Aenean id sem sit amet est vestibulum feugiat. \
Duis rutrum, ligula id dapibus molestie, velit tellus interdum erat, id fringilla mi metus vel neque. Pellentesque dolor arcu, imperdiet vel sodales vitae, egestas ut ligula. Curabitur sapien erat, congue a lacinia sed, accumsan id ipsum. Praesent sit amet tellus neque, id placerat lacus. Etiam nec tortor tortor, nec facilisis nulla. Aenean dui metus, rutrum a fringilla eget, porta ut nisi. Vestibulum volutpat tempor nibh, nec porta risus molestie eu. In metus ipsum, ultricies at posuere ac, tristique sit amet lorem. Sed et quam augue. Aenean eget vestibulum erat. Sed neque orci, luctus a sollicitudin at, rhoncus nec neque. Sed blandit, metus non pharetra semper, nulla ante suscipit orci, nec ultricies erat ipsum vel risus. Pellentesque a neque est.";
var partial = "sed"
var regExp = new RegExp("("+partial+")","gi");
document.write(str.replace(regExp,'<span style="color:red">$1</span>'));
</script>
```

Comment: Not quite @mplungjan. Searching a string isn't quite the problem I'm having, where I AM having an issue is more a question of approach than code.